# SurrealDB indexes for INSIDE

Tags: surrealdb

I'm looking into the documentation of surrealdb, considering whether I should use it rather than postgresql for my next project.

However, the documentation on building indexes seems to be quite sparse.

If I understand correctly, for a toy example I can find all objects for which "foo" is in a list with this command

```
SELECT * FROM objects WHERE "foo" INSIDE list_field
```

However, this will obviously not be indexed by default. How can I add an index, that makes this kind of where clause fast, similar to postgresql's GIN indices?

Answer (score 0):

Indexes can be made via fairly standard syntax, as documented [here](https://docs.surrealdb.com/docs/surrealql/statements/define/indexes/)

Ex:

```
DEFINE INDEX userAgeIndex ON TABLE user COLUMNS age;
```

As for index on a list, like postgres GIN, I have not tried myself, but it reads as if it may just work by default. I found this on the feature page:

"... Table indexes can be specified for a column, multiple columns, and have support for all nested fields **including arrays and objects**."